# How to add two durations in javascript or angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, time

So I want to be able to do mathematical operations on durations of songs. I'm developing in angular but even answers in javascript would be helpful. ultimately to (and this may seem silly, but humor me) take a travel time and figure out what tracks to play such that arrival and the end of a song are within 10 seconds of each other.

I can't figure out how to do operations on time values! Can anyone give me some instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Moment.js durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) may be a viable option for you:

```
const first = moment.duration(2, 'minutes');
const second = moment.duration(30, 'seconds');
const result = first.add(second);
```